# Add to home screen not working

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, bookmarks

I am trying to add a bookmark to my home screen on my android device, but it is not working.

I tried both Firefox 38.0 and Android Browser which both have this option and none of them was able to create the shortcut. I also tried various websites to confirm that it is not a website problem, still nothing.

Is there something wrong with my phone, what do I have to do to get this working?

Comment: How are you adding these bookmarks?

Comment: @zain.ali depending on the browser, for firefox you can add a bookmark then long-tap it and tap add to homescreen or another way is from the menu page > add to homescreen

Comment: Try doing it this way  http://www.cnet.com/uk/how-to/adding-one-touch-bookmarks-to-your-androids-home-screen/

Comment: @zain.ali well all devices also have a bookmark shortcut in their menu but I want to know why the browser functionality is not working and if I can fix it.

Comment: Which Android device, version, and launcher are you using? That feature is working absolutely fine in my Android 4.4.2 and 5.0.2.

Comment: I have found that this feature will not work when 'Easy Mode' is turned on..

Comment: Same proble here on my ASUS Memopad. Can add shortcuts to the homepage from Chrome but when you click on the link, Chrome re-opens but it doesn't open the website